# How do I encode a word with a hyphen like "money-back" in XML-RPC?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xml-parsing

I am trying to post using XML-RCP but when this word and character "-" is there it won't post.
How do i properly code this word in XML?

```
money-back
```

Comment: Please add a small code-example to your question. This can depend on library used. This is important so that future user can find userful information here (e.g. which Worpdress PHP function are you calling or are you calling a Wordpress XML-RPC function?).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the numeric character reference `&#8211;`.